# String loops in Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, counter

I have two pools of strings and I would like to do a loop over both. For example, if I want to put two labeled apples in one plate I'll write:

```
basket1 = ['apple#1', 'apple#2', 'apple#3', 'apple#4']
    for fruit1 in basket1:

       basket2 = ['apple#1', 'apple#2', 'apple#3', 'apple#4']
       for fruit2 in basket2:

            if fruit1 == fruit2:
                print 'Oops!'

            else:
                print "New Plate = %s and %s" % (fruit1, fruit2)
```

However, I don't want order to matter -- for example I am considering apple#1-apple#2 equivalent to apple#2-apple#1. What's the easiest way to code this?

I'm thinking about making a counter in the second loop to track the second basket and not starting from the point-zero in the second loop every time.

Comment: I don't see `orange`s in your above code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change inequality (`!=`) to less than (`<`), and your lists (baskets) are sorted and the same, you won't get (b,a) once you have (a,b).

So

```
fruits = ['apple#1', 'apple#2', 'apple#3', 'apple#4']
[(f1, f2) for f1 in fruits for f2 in fruits if f1 != f2]
```

becomes

```
fruits = ['apple#1', 'apple#2', 'apple#3', 'apple#4']
[(f1, f2) for f1 in fruits for f2 in fruits if f1 < f2]
```

If, however, you have two distinct lists,

```
fruits1 = ['apple#1', 'apple#2', 'apple#3', 'apple#4']
fruits2 = ['apple#1', 'apple#2', 'apple#3', 'apple#4', 'orange#1', 'orange#2']
```

You could still use the technique from above with a slight modification:

```
[(f1, f2) for f1 in fruits1 for f2 in fruits2 if f1 < f2]
```

Comment: Nice solution -- you could generalize in case there are actually two different lists.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to just use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

for tup in combinations(basket1,2):
    print 'New Plate = {} and {}'.format(*tup)

New Plate = apple#1 and apple#2
New Plate = apple#1 and apple#3
New Plate = apple#1 and apple#4
New Plate = apple#2 and apple#3
New Plate = apple#2 and apple#4
New Plate = apple#3 and apple#4
```

Comment: No need to materialize the combinations with `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

If, you have two distinct lists or you cannot compare with one fruit to another.

```
from itertools import product

basket1 = ['apple#1', 'apple#2', 'apple#3', 'apple#4']
basket2 = ['apple#3', 'apple#4', 'apple#5', 'apple#6']

result = []

for tup in product(basket1, basket2):
    if (tup[0] != tup[1]) and (set(tup) not in result):
        result.append(set(tup))
        print "New Plate = %s and %s" % (tup[0], tup[1])

New Plate = apple#1 and apple#3
New Plate = apple#1 and apple#4
New Plate = apple#1 and apple#5
New Plate = apple#1 and apple#6
New Plate = apple#2 and apple#3
New Plate = apple#2 and apple#4
New Plate = apple#2 and apple#5
New Plate = apple#2 and apple#6
New Plate = apple#3 and apple#4
New Plate = apple#3 and apple#5
New Plate = apple#3 and apple#6
New Plate = apple#4 and apple#5
New Plate = apple#4 and apple#6
```